# Xamarin Forms - use pinch gesture only on image rather than entire screen

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Forms, how do we restrict the pinch gesture to zoom only on an image rather than the entire screen?

I have the following in my XAML and thought that wrapping my image in the PinToZoomContainer would do it but it still zooms the whole screen.

```
<local:ContentRatioContainer>
    <local:PinchToZoomContainer>
        <local:PinchToZoomContainer.Content>
            <Image Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding PreviewImage}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" x:Name="bigImg" >
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <PinchGestureRecognizer PinchUpdated="OnPinchUpdated" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
        </local:PinchToZoomContainer.Content>
    </local:PinchToZoomContainer>
</local:ContentRatioContainer>


public PinchToZoomContainer()
{
     var pinchGesture = new PinchGestureRecognizer();
     pinchGesture.PinchUpdated += OnPinchUpdated;
     GestureRecognizers.Add(pinchGesture);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct this by,

```
public PinchToZoomContainer()
{
     var pinchGesture = new PinchGestureRecognizer();
     pinchGesture.PinchUpdated += OnPinchUpdated;
     bigImg.GestureRecognizers.Add(pinchGesture);
}
```